# How to place divs over background image and keeping relative position and size when the browser is resized

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am trying to place 4 divs over a background image that would keep relative position and size as the browser is resized.

Here is the desired layout:
[image]

I have a big background (pink) that is placed with:

```
#screenFiller {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background-size: contain;
        background-image: url("myimg.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

There are 4 main divs (red boxes). The two tops ones (side by side) contain a button each (blue boxes) with text (white squiggly lines) above the buttons but still in the red. I am positioning the divs next to each other using:

```
.flex {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: Left;
        flex: none;
    }
```

The main problem I am having is with the two top divs in that one is not keeping its height (it shrinks to content). I do understand that I will need to handle reducing the text size using a media query or something.

The stripped-down HTML looks like:

```
 <div class="flex ">
            <div class="boxme">
                <div>
                    <p class="boldtext">Blha blah balh</p>
                    <div style="margin:10%;">
                        <button type="button" class="bigbut gborder5" onclick="window.location.href=''">Syart New</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                
            </div>
            <div class="boxme marl100">
                <div>
                    <p class="boldtext">blah</p>
                    <div>
                        <button type="button" class="bigbut gborder5" onclick="window.location.href=''">Start New</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
               
            </div>
        </div>
```

With boxme being:

```
.boxme {
        background-color: white;
        width: 25%;
        height: 10%;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Finally, all four divs are wrapped in a div with the following css

```
.relpos {
        position: relative;
        top: 36%;
        left: 4%;
        width: 85%
    }
```

Please feel free to take me on an alternate path.

Bootstrap is available if that helps but currently, everything is just HTML and CSS.

Thank you in advanced for any consideration.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on what those four divs are to be positioned relative to? Are they always to be at the bottom left corner of the viewport or are they always to be over the same part of the background image?

Comment: Always over the same part of the background

Comment: To keep the elements in the same position relative to the image position them using % relative to the image, not relative to the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you never want to have fixed width, height, margin or paddings.

For your question, your flex values should be to put your content in the bottom left corner:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: row; // default
}
```

Here is the full example that can be run as code snippet:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  background-color: #fcf;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  gap: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container>div {
  background-color: #faa;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <p>Text</p>
    <button>Cick</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>Text</p>
    <button>Cick</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would strongly advise you to **learn the fundamentals of html and css** from other resources.

Comment: Please do not link to codepens, use the stacksnippet (`Ctrl+M` or `<>`-button) instead. All answers and questions must be self-containing and not relay on external resources.